# Calculate percentage based on input fields in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am using AngularJS. I have two input fields: total marks and marks obtained, as well as a 3rd field which is percentage. Now after entering total marks and marks obtained, I need to calculate the percentage automatically.

Here is my html :

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label">Total Marks</label>
    <input type="text"
           class="form-control input_field"
           name="totalMarks"
           data-ng-model="student.totalMarks" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label">Marks Obtained</label>
    <input type="text"
           class="form-control input_field"
           name="marksObtained"
           data-ng-model="student.marksObtained" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label">Percentage</label>
    <input type="text"
           class="form-control input_field"
           value={{ ((student.marksObtained/student.totalMarks)*100).toFixed(2) }}
           name="rank"
           data-ng-model="student.rank" />
</div>
```

Can anyone tell me how to auto generate rank field with percentage as soon as I enter marks obtained. Currently, I am doing as shown above but it is not working.

Comment: Try with ng-value

Comment: I tried but not working.

Comment: Why don't you just put watch on your student.totalMarks and student.marksObtained on your controller and on change just do the calculation - on student.rank, and keep only ng-model on field

Comment: Yea i used watchers and it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure that your calcul for percentage is exact, but this Plunkr is working with a watcher on student properties.

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope){
  $scope.$watchGroup(['student.totalMarks', 'student.marksObtained'], function(){
    if($scope.student.marksObtained !== undefined && $scope.student.totalMarks !== undefined)
      $scope.student.rank = (($scope.student.marksObtained/$scope.student.totalMarks)*100).toFixed(2);
  })
});
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/NsNge0mzrgjjUgBZ332p?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

You can try assigning your calculation inline, like this:

```
  <input ng-model="student.rank" ng-value="student.rank = ((student.marksObtained/student.totalMarks)*100).toFixed(2)">
```

[Running Example on JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b30msjzj/)

Answer (score 0):

It does not work because your input is linked to a ng-model.
There is two ways to solve this problem :

- Setup a watcher on `student.totalMars` and `student.marksObtained`, and update `student.rank` with new value.
- Do not link your percentage to `student.rank` and just set the value as you did.

You can check [here](http://jsfiddle.net/g147xfLx/) for the second way.

Comment: Its working.but can u tell how to get that value to ng-model so that i can pass it along with student object for saving?

Answer (score 0):

In your controller, add the following function and variable :

```
function getPercentage() {
    // dividing by zero is bad !!!
    let ratio = $scope.student.marksObtained / ($scope.student.totalMarks || 1);
    return (ratio * 100).toFixed(2);
}
$scope.student.percentage = getPercentage();
```

Then change the last `<input />` of your view to :

```
<input type="text"
       class="form-control input_field"
       ng-value="student.percentage"
       name="rank" />
```

If you want your input to have two-way data binding, use `ng-model` instead of `ng-value`.